# table cell shading overlaps to nearby cells

Tags: tables, colortbl

I have a latex table as follows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|@{\,}c@{\,}|@{\,}c@{\,}|@{\,}c@{\,}|@{\,}c@{\,}|}
\hline
Column1 & Column2 & Column3 & Column4 \\
\hline
A & \cellcolor[gray]{0.5} & D & E \\
\hline
 &  &  & F \\
\hline
 &  &  & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The cell color is overlaping to the nearby columns. It may be because of `@{\,}` I used with tabular to remove text padding in columns(It is required since my actual table has more width). Anyone know how prevent the cell shading from overlapping to other cells in this case?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi, I have added a working example and refined my code a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`colortbl` adds a padding `\tabcolsep` wide; instead of using `@{\,}` you should reduce `\tabcolsep`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.3em}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Column1 & Column2 & Column3 & Column4 \\
\hline
A & \cellcolor[gray]{0.5} & D & E \\
\hline
 &  &  & F \\
\hline
 &  &  & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For information, with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (with the key `color-inside` --- alias: `colortbl-like`), you have directly the expected ouptut with your code.

However, as said by egreg, the good solution to your problem is to change `\tabcolsep`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{|@{\,}c@{\,}|@{\,}c@{\,}|@{\,}c@{\,}|@{\,}c@{\,}|}[color-inside]
\hline
Column1 & Column2 & Column3 & Column4 \\
\hline
A & \cellcolor[gray]{0.5} & D & E \\
\hline
 &  &  & F \\
\hline
 &  &  & \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]